# SQL: Get row using dynamic date

Tags: mysql

First let me start by saying I am a Junior so I do apologise if this is a really stupid question or not possible.

I have a `WHERE` clause in an SQL script that gets rows if the date is later than a certain date. Like so:

```
WHERE 
    u.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01')
```

The **month** and **day** will always be the same but the year needs to be changed every year with the current year. So, next April I will have to make a change to the code to read:

```
WHERE 
    u.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-04-01')
```

I was wondering if it's possible to make the year update to the current year **IF** the day and month are past **1st April**

Comment: What type is `created`?

Comment: @BenM It is `INT` (11)

Comment: So you're storing a Unix timestamp in that field? Change the field to `DATE` and this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `DATE_FORMAT` with the `NOW()` function as the source for the current year:

```
WHERE
    u.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-04-01'))
```

### Demo

Comment: NOW() will provide current date and hence current year, whereas as per question, the requirement is to pick current year only after 01-04, so the better option is to check date and month of the current date

Comment: @AmanChhabra If the OP wants to avoid hard-coding April 1 of the current year, then my answer solves that problem.  As to whether it's the _best_ solution, I don't know, but it is a valid solution.

Comment: @AmanChhabra In this case, you're really suggesting that the OP should be storing a date rather than a UNIX timestamp.  This may be right, but there are certainly cases where storing UNIX time is valid.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do understand, but the requirement here is to  make a check of u.created with a 01-04-LASTYEAR if the current date has not crossed 1st April or else user 01-04-CUR YEAR. Requirement says "I was wondering if it's possible to make the year update to the current year IF the day and month are past 1st April"

Comment: @AmanChhabra Then you should post the correct answer if you are certain of this.  I have no idea what you're talking about.  We can't do straight date comparisons against a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I accepted your answer. I was hoping to wait for an example and an alternative and then chose the best one for other users to be able to see too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am suggesting to use something like this:   WHERE (NOW() >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-04-01')) and u.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-04-01'))) OR ((NOW() < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-04-01')) and u.created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) ,'%Y-04-01')))

Comment: @Mark I think this is what you were looking for , let me know if thats not the case.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid As explained above, the above given answer does not solve the complete requirement hence downvote, please see my comment above for proper solution.